# How to view a PDF file in its real page size in Evince, same size as printed

Tags: linux, evince

There is a `100%` zoom in level in evince, but it looks obviously not the real page size as printed. How can I achieve this in Evince?

Comment: Your screen is probably close to 100ppi while a typical print resolution for saving documents is 300dpi.  If you are looking at the document at its native resolution, it will appear much larger on-screen.  If you want the physical dimension of the screen to match the dimension of the printed output, you will need to play with the zoom.

Comment: @fixer1234 I can definitely manually adjust the zooming... Just want to know whether there is a shortcut.

Comment: Since screen and print resolutions (and saved resolutions in files) vary, this would be pretty tough to automate in a general utility, and I'm not aware of anything like that.  But you might be able to find something where you figure out the right zoom and then save that setting in a way that you could jump to it with a shortcut or key assignment.  I don't have an answer, but that's a direction to pursue.  Maybe a reader will get an idea from this comment and suggest a solution.

Answer (score 3):

The problem that you have is that, since recent versions of gnome (3.14 maybe), on startup (and resume from suspend, as well) gnome sets the DPI to 96, whatever the real DPI is (which X has always guessed correctly).

That unfortunate design decision with gnome, that does not appear to be justified by HiDPI support (because HiDPI works equally well without that forced DPI setting), forces us to go to the trouble of manually setting the DPI each time (after each reboot or resume).

Say that your true DPI is 185 (as you can determine from Xorg log), if you open a terminal window and do:

```
# xrandr --dpi 185
```

Then 100% in evince and other programs will be the true size (or a very good approximation).

Comment: Does one need to restart the desktop environment after this? Running `xrandr --dpi 96 && evince /usr/share/texmf/doc/latex/preview/preview.pdf` makes no difference compared to running it with `--dpi 185` on Evince 3.38.2 and Cinnamon 4.8.6-2+deb11u1